# How do I remove alpha from legend in geom_boxplot (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha-transparency

I would like to remove the alpha legend in  my final boxplot. My dataframe refers to linear measurements, I need to explore the distributions of these measurements by sex and age class.
 I would also like to have the final legend colors actually matching the alpha ;)! What do you think is the best way to do that?

Many thanks in advance!

[image]

```html
#boxplot with age classes as groups
box1 <- ggplot(tibfib, aes(x = Age.class, y = T1))

#adding sex as group
box2 <- box1 + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Sex, alpha = 0.6), position = position_dodge(0.9)) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#999999", "#E69F00"))


#for labels
sex_names <- c(
  `1` = "Females",
  `2` = "Males")

#final box
box.T1<- box2 + facet_wrap(~Sex, labeller = as_labeller(sex_names))+ theme_bw() + labs(x = "Age classes", y = "Tibial length (mm)")+  labs(fill = "Sex") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00"), name="Sex", breaks=c("1", "2"),labels=c("Females", "Males"))
```

grouped boxplot.

Comment: Get the alpha out of the `aes()` statement. I.e. `geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Sex), alpha = 0.6, ...)`

Comment: or you can do alpha(c("#999999", "#E69F00"),0.6), and use that on your scale_color_manual , then you can do without alpha

Comment: Looks like both of these answers would work for the OP.  [u/StupidWolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12258459/stupidwolf) and/or [u/teunbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11374827/teunbrand), can you post the combination as an answer so that OP can accept and close out the question?  Otherwise, @anna.lisa, you can post the answer and accept it yourself if you find they worked to keep the site clear of "answered but *unanswered*" questions.